# Deserialization Error: InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deserialization

I have this problem and I'm not sure how to solve it... I tried plenty of things and can't find something similar online for help.

Note: Another Scene uses a Script with saving and using the same .dat file, not sure if that's an issue though.

```
public GameObject[] top10 = new GameObject[10];

[System.Serializable]
public class ScoreEntry
{
    public string name;

    public int score;
}

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/hiscores.dat"))
    {
        BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
        var f = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/hiscores.dat", FileMode.Open);

        List<ScoreEntry> hiScores = (List<ScoreEntry>)b.Deserialize(f);
        f.Close();

        for (int i = 0; i == hiScores.Count; i++)
            top10[i].GetComponent<TextMesh>().text += hiScores[i].name + " - " + hiScores[i].score;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `ScoreEntry` class is using fields, not properties.  I believe the serializer/deserializer requires properties.  Try this:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ScoreEntry
{
    public string name {get;set;}

    public int score {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Got this error now: SerializationException: serializationStream supports seeking, but its length is 0
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.NoCheckDeserialize (System.IO.Stream serializationStream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/BinaryFormatter.cs:155)

Comment: are you using an old file that was serialized?  Try creating a new serialized file with this new class change (the properties).  If you are trying to deserialize an older version, it may not have serialized properly.  The error makes it seem like the file doesn't contain any data. This link http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/767580/serialization-exception-error-when-trying-to-load.html suggests `I guess you didn't call formater.serialize in your Save() function.`